# Get server time php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have this script 
1- It gets the time of number of messages sent (time identified by client)
2- Compare it to now time (server time)
3- change the background of each message according to the time difference
Now i have a problem in updating the clock, i update it each second (ajax request) but i think it is making the system heavier. Is there a way i can update the clock (server time) every minute?
This is the script:
javascript:
function to get server time

```
  function gettime()
  {
    $.post('gettimeofday.php',
         function(t){
         document.getElementById('formatted_time').value = t;
   });
     setTimeout("gettime()",1000);
  }
```

php:

```
$server_current_time = time();
echo(date("H:i",$server_current_time));
```

javascript:
function to calculate the time difference:

```
function checkTime(Time_to_send)
{
  var time_from_db = Time_to_send.split(":",2);
  var time_hours = Number(time_from_db[0] * 60 );
  var time_min = Number(time_from_db[1]);
  var time_of_msg = time_hours + time_min;
  var current_time = document.getElementById('formatted_time').value;
  var ct = current_time.split(":",10); 
  var now_hours = Number(ct[0] * 60);
  var now_min = Number(ct[1]);
  var time_live = now_hours + now_min;
  var time_diff = time_of_msg - time_live;
  return (time_diff);
}
```

And after that i check the time difference and change the background color.
I hope you can help me find a solution and if you have any question concerning my question please tell me.

Comment: One AJAX request per second?  Ouch.

Comment: why dont you just get a timestamp from the server once (or once every x seconds (60-300), and on client side ++ the stamp every second and print it in the format you want.

Comment: Rufinus' suggestions is probably the best way of handling this. +1

Answer (score -1):

Sure, perhaps something like this:

PHP:

```
// output the Unix timestamp (integer value)
echo mktime();
```

JavaScript:

```
// now an integer value for easy incrementing
var myTime;

window.onload = function()
{
    setInterval(getTime, 60000);
    setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);
};

function getTime()
{
    $.post('gettimeofday.php', function(t)
    {
        myTime = t;
    });

}

function incrementTime()
{
    myTime++;
}

function checkTime(previousTime)
{
    // convert previousTime to a UnixTimestamp, subtract it from myTime, format it however you want, and return it.
}
```

Comment: I would suggest keeping everything in Unix timestamp format in your code. It is much easier to work with an integer as opposed to having to format/unformat a string every time and perform extra calculations based on that. Then you can just format the date however you want for display purposes only.

Comment: Don't pass strings to setInterval, pass functions. So just `setInterval(getTime, 60000);` and `setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yeah, I always forget how that syntax goes. Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Travesty3 You are synchronizing the time between server and client every 1 minute am I correct?

Comment: @4LeaveCover: Yes, that is what it looks like. Sorry, I haven't looked at this answer in over four years, so I don't remember it at all. But yes, that does appear to be what's happening here.